# Build Failed: import "example.com/mysql" is a program ,not an importable package

Tags: module, path

I am connecting to database in gcp console by creating new function using golang with sample code with database is created already using existing one
But giving error that "Build Failed: import "example.com/module" is a program ,not an importable package" if example.com is removed then it shows error "must contain dot in first path element before slash"

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Go MySQL Tutorial")

    // Open up our database connection.
    // I've set up a database on my local machine using phpmyadmin.
    // The database is called testDb
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "username:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")

    // if there is an error opening the connection, handle it
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    // defer the close till after the main function has finished
    // executing
    defer db.Close()

}
```

and for go.mod

```
module example.com/mysql  
go 1.20
require github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.7.1
```

I am expecting to connect database using golang in GCP console